# How to modify value in data.json with react

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am trying to modify a value in my data.json. I am working on a web entertainment app for my portfolio

[image]

So I want to modify the value   "isBookmarked"  in my data.json

here it is a part of my data.json

```
type here{
    "title": "Beyond Earth",
    "thumbnail": {
      "trending": {
        "small": "./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/trending/small.jpg",
        "large": "./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/trending/large.jpg"
      },
      "regular": {
        "small": "./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/regular/small.jpg",
        "medium": "./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/regular/medium.jpg",
        "large": "./assets/thumbnails/beyond-earth/regular/large.jpg"
      }
    },
    "year": 2019,
    "category": "Movie",
    "rating": "PG",
    "isBookmarked": false,
    "isTrending": true
  },
```

with the IsBookmarded value I know which of the movies I did bookmark and I need to modify the value directly in json so after I can display only the bookmarked one and then toggle the one I don't want anymore in the bookmark section. But the thing I am trying to do with useEffect it's fetching the data, and make a copy of it and put that in a copy of the data with state but there is a problem

```
type hereconst [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("./data.json")
        .then(res => setData(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
            
        
        
    }, []);
    
        function handleUpdateData(index){
        const newData = [...data];
        console.log(data[0].isBookmarked)  // Here it's not working , 
        // newData[index].isBookmarked = newData[index].isBookmarked ? false : true;
        // setData(newData);
    };
```

The problem it's that console.log(data) work and console.log(data[0]) work too

but if I want to do  console.log(data[0].isBookmarked)  the console is telling me that the

isBookmarded is not defined so I don't know what to do I am bit lost

Answer (score 0):

In the frontend of `React` you cannot update the `.json` file directly. You can import (or fetch) the .json, store it on state, and manipulate the state - however the original .json file will remain in-tact.

If you want to be able to update the .json file, I would ask "why not use a simple datastore?" Look into Firebase / Firestore - very easy and fun to use - the entire store is JSON based and can be manipulated from your React frontend.

Otherwise you are looking into more complicated solutions which involved:

- Sending a request to a backend server or cloud function
- Using `fs` to write a file to the server to overwrite your `.json` file
- Refreshing your client so that it loads the newly updated `.json` file

These 3 steps are much much more difficult than just using an actual database / datastore. MySQL, Postgres, Firestore are all options.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) which you will be able to send HTTP requests to the endpoint and update `data.json`